# Merge multiple SearchQuerySet

Tags: django, django-haystack, searchqueryset

I use Haystack and solr for a global search with multiple models , i try to use different filter on models, but at the end i have to return 1 queryset, i don't find how to merge this.

```
#views
from haystack.generic_views import SearchView

class search(SearchView):

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super(search, self).get_queryset()
        q1 = queryset.models(Event).filter(...)
        q2 = queryset.models(News).filter(...)
        queryset = q1 | q2 #don't work
        queryset = list(chain(q1, q2)) #don't work
        return queryset.order_by('-pub_date','cname')
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have find a way by modifiy the context, but im not sure this is the best...

```
def excludeResults(results):
    for i in results:
        if i.model == Event and i.date < datetime.now():    
        results.remove(i)

    return results

class search(SearchView):
    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super(search, self).get_queryset()
        return queryset.filter(visible = True).order_by('cname','-pub_date')

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(search, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        context['page_obj'].object_list = excludeResults(context['page_obj'].object_list)


        return context
```

maybe a best solution?